# Charting.DataPointCollection how to get a Range?

Tags: c#, charts

I have a Charting.DataPointCollection and want to get only a part of the data. In a List you can do it like `list.GetRange(int index, int count);` but in DataPointCollection you don't have GetRange().

I had the idea of using something like that: `DataPoints.Where(elem => DataPoints.IndexOf(elem) >= i && DataPoints.IndexOf(elem) <= j)` but now i have an IEnumerable instead of a DataPointCollection...

How can i get a DataPointCollection as a Part of another DataPointCollection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead of using `IndexOf()`

```
DataPoints.Skip(number).Take(number);
```

As for getting result as the `DataPointCollection`, I haven't found any reasonable way of converting it directly. Only thing I came up with is create a new `Series` and insert the data points one by one to its `Points` collection in a loop.

Comment: I load some data in a own DataPoint structure and have to calculate some points and after that i add them to the Series. So i insert the data points already one by one. My idea was to make it faster by using a DataPointCollection instead my DataPoint structure... But thanks anyway.