# Fastest way to hold lists of data and have them readable while changing a data list

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have a class `Data` and for a fixed amount of days i want to save some lists of `Data` objects.

I can do it like that: `List<List<Data>>` or `List<Data>[amount]` or `Dictionary<DateTime, List<Data>>` or whatever i want.

For example i have data from 1.1.2000 to 4.1.2000.

I want now move it to: 2.1.2000 to 5.1.2000 (move one day in the future)
So i have to delete the first and move and add the new data at the end.

I also need the other way: 31.12.1999 to 3.1.2000 (move a day in the past)
Now i have to delete the last and move and insert new data at the beginning.

My problem: i load the data asynchronous while i read data from that structure. I want, that data reading is possible at (nearly) every time.

So. What is the best way? An array is the fastest method when i fill the data. `List<List<Data>>` is also good and a Dictionary is veeeery slow (in my test first both around 0.5 sec while Dic around 2 sec.).

But when i want to move that array, i can't read while i'm not ready moving the data. When i use a List i don't have to touch the middle (only delete first and add at the end; faster?) and with the dictionary i can access all the time?

The Data saves around 10.000 datasets and i usualy have around 10 Data elements in a List. And i have around 3-4 days loaded.

Edit:

The goal is to show parts of the data in a chart with mschart. I read files, load them into my structure (my `List<List<Data>>` or whatever) and convert the data into `Charting.DataPointCollection` and let the Chart show it (converting the data directly and hold a `DataPointCollection` instead of `Data` didn't seem to go, see my question here: [Charting.DataPointCollection how to get a Range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327721/charting-datapointcollection-how-to-get-a-range))

When i want to get some information about e.g. 2.1.2000 8:00 to 10:00, i search in the structure for my day (i search for the right `List<Data>`) then i choose the right dataset (search in the `List<Data>`) and after that i search the right data points in `Data`.
 I collect them and apply some algorithms to reduce the data points (e.g. Douglas-Peucker). After that i give the data to the chart.

When i only load the data points without the structure, my chart is too slow.

To give the user the ability to move forward (without waiting until the data is loaded) i need to preload the data. And thats why i load asynchronous some days more.
In this case the user can move and when a neighbor day is needed, i can show the preloaded data and load asynchronous the next needed day.

Comment: This sounds like over-engineering to me.  What is the end goal and where is the data stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

It turns out there's a name for what you are looking for: a deque.
Deque is short for double-ended queue, a queue that allows insertion/removal on both ends.

I implemented:

- a concurrent lock-free `ConcurrentDeque<T>` with Peek, Pop and Push operations on both ends, which seems to suit your needs perfectly;
- and a simpler non-concurrent `Deque<T>`.

You can find the source on [GitHub](https://github.com/dcastro/DequeNET) (feel free to contribute) and the NuGet package here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DequeNET/

### Old answer

Sounds like a perfect description of a [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), a thread-safe FIFO (first-in first-out) data structure.

Use `Enqueue` to add an item to the back of the queue, and `TryDequeue` to remove the head of the queue.

Other threads can still iterate through the collection: the `GetEnumerator` implementation returns a snapshot of the collection at the time of the call.

---

A dictionary is definitely not a good idea. It looks like you want your items sorted by order of insertion: a dictionary (hash table) makes no guarantee whatsoever about the order of the elements.

Comment: Is it also possible to add an item to the head of the queue and remove from the back of the queue?

Comment: @fedab No. I thought you only needed to add to the back? "So i have to delete the first and move and add the new data at the end."

Comment: I also need the other direction. Moving backward and forward in time. Sorry, i edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Hmmm I guess there's nothing built into the framework for that... Maybe [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx)? Give it a try

Comment: @fedab Whenever I have the time, I'll try implementing a two-way concurrent queue myself. I'll report back.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) It seems that i can't use `BlockingCollection<T>` because it only gives me a Take() function without the possibility to choose what element i want to take.

Comment: @fedab turns out what you needed was a thread-safe deque - a double ended queue. I implemented one myself, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `Dictionary<DateTime,List<Data>>` . Now, when new data arrives, you can invoke a function like so:

```
TimeSpan tsNumberOfDaysToHoldData=TimeSpan.FromDays(5);
var DataHolder= new Dictionary<DateTime,List<Data>>()

private void AddNewDayData(DateTime NewDay,List<Data> NewData)
{
   DataHolder[NewDay]=NewData;
   List<DateTime> ExpiredDates=new List<DateTime>();
   foreach(var DayCursor in DataHolder.Keys)
   {
       if(NewDay-DayCursor>tsNumberOfDaysToHoldData)
       {
         ExpiredDates.Add(DayCursor);
       }
   }
   ExpiredDate.ForEach(c=>DataHolder.Remove(c))
 }
```

This function checks all the keys in the dictionary, marks the ones representing expired dates, and removes them from the DataHolder.